# Visual Studio column selection - Select by word, not square

Tags: visual-studio, ide

This seems like something I would have found hundreds of topics on. Yet I didn't find a single one. I wonder if no one cares or if I just overlooked something obvious.

In **Visual Studio** when you **select a column** and want to **select the word your cursor is at in each line**, when you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+**(ARROW KEY)**, then it doesn't select by word as it **SHOULD**, but instead it selects a *square*.

---

***BAD BEHAVIOUR*** (which VS has)***:***

[image]

---

***GOOD BEHAVIOUR*** (which would be expected, and is in every other IDE)***:***

[image]

---

The Visual Studio ALT select is rendered useless in half the cases, actually in every case where you don't have the "coordinates" precisely the same on every line.

---

***EDIT***

I seem to have to explain why the VS behavior is bad, people apparently consider it ok. So the problem is that when you column select in VS, and you have it exactly like in the example, or even without tabs, you'd copy some =, though they won't be everywhere.

If you select a column like VS Code or JetBrains has it, you'll just copy WHAT IS NEEDED and that OBVIOUSLY being just the words in the column.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you, but you may not like it. It's using the new [Multi-Caret Support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/08/30/improving-your-productivity-in-the-visual-studio-editor/) in Visual Studio 2017.

Here is my example code where I want to copy only the property names (sorry for lack of inline images):
[Multi-Caret Code Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eelaT.png)

1. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + **Click** to click and add a caret to the end of each word. (If you screw up and click somewhere you didn't mean, like I do many times, then reclick to remove that caret and click on the correct spot.)
   [Multi-Caret End of Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXVGh.png)
2. Now hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and hit the <kbd>←</kbd> Left Arrow. This will select to the beginning of the current word on each line.
   [Multi-Caret Word Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3u0s.pnge)
3. Copy/paste as you wish

Comment: This is a somewhat decent solution but it shouldn't require the mouse to click in exactly the right spot. Other editors (like VS Code) select by-word when using Shift with multi-cursor via ALT-SHIFT-Up/Down. The mouse shouldn't be required. MS Just needs to implement the same consistent functionality as other editors. I feel they took an easy way out just to mark another item off the UserVoice request list. Or maybe I'm just not seeing where to turn that option on in Visual Studio.